# I'm trying to run this code initialize pygame midi code but it returns an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to run this code just to see if all is ok but it returns an error.

```
import pygame.midi

pygame.midi.init()
```

It returns this error:

```
ALSA lib conf.c:3558:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so (/usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so: libasound_module_conf_pulse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
ALSA lib seq.c:935:(snd_seq_open_noupdate) Unknown SEQ default
```

Comment: Did you try to install the required package (something like `libasound`)?

Comment: @Valentino Yes. No luck.

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit python on a 64-bit operating system? If so you'll need to install the 32-bit package, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/333654/edit).

Answer (score 0):

The path `/usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so` is wrong. The `libasound_module_conf_pulse.so` is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib`, at least on my 20.04 Ubuntu. So what I did was I made a `alsa-lib` directory in `/usr/lib/` and copied the files from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib` to the newly made `alsa-lib` directory. I really don't think this is a good long-term solution but at least I got my code running.